# Adding variable amounts of variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

What should I do if I have a variable number of variables and I want the sum of variables?
For Eg.

```
import random
X = random.randint(1, 25)
Y = random.randint(1, 5) + X
for A in range(X, Y):
    W = random.randint(1, 10)  # you want sum of all W produced
    # W = W+W     --> will not work
```

From this very random system, I want to extract the sum of all W. 
something like W = W + W won't work, the value of the previous result cannot be stored

I would like you to not edit the previously given part and get the answer because I have tried to reconstruct the code to be smaller.
This question is from a bigger code with me having no scope of using
W += ...

Comment: initialize W to 0 before the loop `W = 0` and inside the loop add the randint value `W += random.randint(1, 10)`

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki please review the edited question. Thank you

Comment: @Seshrut can you define a variable outside of the `for` loop?

Comment: Yes absolutely.

Comment: Then simply do `S = 0` outside the loop and `S += W` inside

Comment: ahh... didn't think about that, please write it in the form of the answer so everyone can see it @matszwecja

Comment: Use `sum`. It's in the Python documentation.

Comment: @CharlieClark can you show us some examples in the answers. That will be appreciated. :)

Comment: The documentation includes examples. It would be very much appreciated if you actually read that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the user doesn't appear to care about documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need a for loop for that, simply sum over a generator expression.

```
import random
X = random.randint(1, 25)
Y = random.randint(1, 5) + X
W = sum(random.randint(1, 10) for _ in range(X, Y))
```

If all the lines of the code you provided have to stay intact here's what you can do:

```
import random
X = random.randint(1, 25)
Y = random.randint(1, 5) + X
S = 0
for A in range(X, Y):
    W = random.randint(1, 10)  # you want sum of all W produced
    S += W
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import random
X = random.randint(1, 25)
Y = random.randint(1, 5) + X
W = 0
for A in range(X, Y):
    W += random.randint(1, 10)  


print(W)
```

Based on [@Sembei Norimaki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2261062/sembei-norimaki) answer

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).